# Understanding Turtle Graphics Listen and Exitonclick Method

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to understand precisely the functioning of those two functions

I am just starting to learn Python through some online courses, and an exercise required the use of the turtle package to draw things from the keyboard. The solution uses `screen.listen()`, but trying the listen method, works exactly the same. So I guess in this case they are equivalent. The code is simply this:

```
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(move_forward, key="w")
screen.onkeypress(move_backwards, key= "s")
screen.onkeypress(turn_left, key= "a")
screen.onkeypress(turn_right, key= "d")
screen.onkeypress(reset, key="space")
screen.exitonclick()
```

where I spare you the definition of all the functions. The point is: what does `listen()` and `exitonclick()` do? I mean, in a program, I imagine the computer reading line by line and then following instructions (at least in an interpreted language like Python), but in this case, it seems like the program is entering a sort of stop state where it constantly waits for my instructions until I click to exit, I guess due to `screen.exitonclick()`. For instance, I imagined that `screen.exitonclick()` was stopping the program and saying "Ok, you stop until the user clicks, then go on with the rest of the program", and if `screen.listen()` is "active", it catches the keyboard inputs and does what it must do. Am I correct? Or how do they work in fact?

Comment: Your understanding seems more or less correct, although `exitonclick` exits rather than proceeds. See [listen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.listen) and [exitonclick](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.exitonclick) in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The solution uses `screen.listen()`, but trying with `turtle.listen()` it
> works exactly the same, so I guess in this case they are equivalent.

They are equivalent, `turtle.listen()` is a convenience (beginner) top-level turtle function that calls the `listen()` method on the singular screen instance.

> I imagined that screen.exitonclick() was stopping the program and
> saying "Ok, you stop until the user clicks, then go on with the rest
> of the program"

The `exitonclick()` method installs an event handler for the screen object that exits when the mouse is clicked, and *then* turns control over to the (tkinter) event handler just as `mainloop()` does.  The program doesn't stop, it *waits* for events.  In this case, the program doesn't continue when the mouse is clicked except to exit it completely.

> if screen.listen() is "active", it catches the keyboard inputs and
> does what it must do.

The model is only one window is the "active listener" on the screen which can receive keyboard input.  The `listen()` method makes the turtle window that "active listener", otherwise keyboard clicks have no effect on the turtle window.  There is no method to give up being the "active listener" but screen methods like `textinput()` and `numinput()` take over as "active listener" which is why you have to call `listener()` again after invoking them if you still want to receive keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

The `ExitOnClick()` function closes the window on the click with the mouse. The turtle `listen()` function makes the computer listen closely for any key pressed events. For more information you can visit the following Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html
(I'm Guessing your doing the 100 Days Of code course with angela.)
Good luck!

Comment: Yes! So far I am really liking it, after this I wanted to delve deeper into data analysis though (she's more of a web developer if I am not mistaken)

Comment: Glad your enjoying it!